# How to make background all over the header section?

Tags: css, background

I want to divide my page into 3 sections, with 3 different backgrounds:
`top_bg`, `middle_bg` and `bottom_bg`.

The problem is that the background has a padding. I want it to show from the start of the page and next 500 pixels in height.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top_part">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      <h1>My website name</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

And here my CSS:

```css
header {
    background-image: url(images/top_bg.gif) ;
    height: 500px;
}

.top_part img {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80;
}

.top_part h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Look what I meant, if you didn't understood: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nYmG.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser default styles leads to `margin` and `padding` of the HTML elements, you need to reset those..

Use

```
* { /* This resets all elements default margins and paddings */
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

else use CSS **[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** stylesheet to reset elements which have **default** `margins` and `padding`

Comment: Small note. HTML elements don't have the default margins and paddings, but there are a browser's default styles which is always better to reset

Comment: Global reset is not good. Use only `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`. Also, `0px` => the `px` is not necessary when a value is `0`.

Comment: @NikolaK. yea but I generally prefer global reset, moreover I use px for a safer side, I know it's not necessary but following good practice is better right?